# Errors modifying an existing class using JavaAssist

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, java-assist

I'm working on the following CodeWars challenge :

https://www.codewars.com/kata/hack-22/train/java

Here's what I've written :

```
public static Yossarian loophole() throws Throwable {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    //Loader cl = new Loader(pool);
    CtClass yossarianClass = pool.get("Yossarian");
    int modifiers = yossarianClass.getDeclaredMethod("isCrazy").getModifiers();
    if(Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)) {
        System.out.println("Removing Final");
        int notFinalModifier = Modifier.clear(modifiers, Modifier.FINAL);
        yossarianClass.getDeclaredMethod("isCrazy").setModifiers(notFinalModifier);
        yossarianClass.rebuildClassFile();
    }
    final CtClass saneYossarianClass = ClassPool.getDefault().makeClass("SaneYossarian");
    saneYossarianClass.setSuperclass(yossarianClass);
    final CtMethod overrideMethod = CtNewMethod.make("public boolean isCrazy() { return true; }", saneYossarianClass);
    saneYossarianClass.addMethod(overrideMethod);
    final Class<?> aClass = saneYossarianClass.toClass(Yossarian.class.getClassLoader(), Yossarian.class.getProtectionDomain());
    return (Yossarian) aClass.newInstance();
}
```

and I get the following error :

**Exception in thread "main" javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.ClassFormatError: class SaneYossarian overrides final method isCrazy.()Z**

Which makes no sense!  I used JavaAssist precisely to modify the original class.  I'm not looking for a solution to the challenge, just an understanding of what I did wrong in the step where I modified the class.  Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE** : I also tried directly modifying the method in the base class to return true,

Comment: (no knowledge) that does makes me think how actually javaassist works internally - maybe it does not modify the class but only extends it ;)

Comment: And I am beeing able to reproduce that. Nonsense ;)

Comment: For some reasons set modifiers are "not in effect". You will get the same problem when superclass will be final and you will try to remove that modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
final Class<?> aClass = saneYossarianClass.toClass(Yossarian.class.getClassLoader(), Yossarian.class.getProtectionDomain());
```

use

```
 final Class<?> aClass = saneYossarianClass.toClass();
```

For some reasons this works for me:

```
public final class SomeClassHavingFinals {

    public final void sayHelloBoy() {
        System.out.println("I am saying hello original");
    }
}
```

And:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
            throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass clazz = pool.get("testapp.SomeClassHavingFinals");
        clazz.defrost();
        clazz.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
        clazz.getDeclaredMethod("sayHelloBoy").setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
        clazz.toClass();

        CtClass extension = pool.makeClass("SomeExtension");
        extension.setSuperclass(clazz);
        final CtMethod overrideMethod = CtNewMethod.make("public void sayHelloBoy() { System.out.println(\"Im overriden\"); }",
                extension);
        extension.addMethod(overrideMethod);
        Object ei = extension.toClass().newInstance();
        ei.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("sayHelloBoy").invoke(ei);
    }
```

outputs

> Im overriden

so it looks like it is working. IDK internals, but it seems that toClass() causes the file definition to be rebuilt.

Comment: Appreciate the response - but this didn't work for me.  Also, if I use toClass() on the base class, I get a duplicate load error :(

Comment: Well, what I have provided is a working, reproduceable example. You don't have that.

Comment: If you add         new SomeClassHavingFinals(); to the beginning of your main method, you'll get the error I'm getting.